# Ckeditor 5 list plugin is not working as expected

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

1.List plugin with ListProperties plugin is not working as expected its showing in Ui but not showing in editor when we are selecting.
any list from dropdown and no errors is shown in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtfdH.png)

this is my json file i even tried to change list plugin version but its same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT4xQ.png)

List plugin is showing in editor UI but not working when clicking any list numbered or bullet list nothing is happening on clicking list in editor
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPpK3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN3uT.png)

this is my code image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5BAw.png)

i have used same as shown in this documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/lists/lists-installation.html#list-properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IV5S.png)

List is only showing in editor UI but not working when clicking it should work as shown in documentation

I hope now its clear what is issue please let me know its solution